# How to get path without parameter from vue router interceptors ‘to’ parameter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I need to get the path of a route without its parameters in vue router interceptor.

```
router.beforeEach(( to, from, next) => {
    console.log(to);
})
```

If the route is `/profile/abc/def` where `abc` and `def` are parameters to the route, I need to get only `/profile` from my interceptors to parameter. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the `console.log` that there is a property called `params` in `to`, it contains route parameters.

Then you get what you want to remove, the rest thing you need to do is to use javascript to remove these parameters from the route.

Comment: sad it's not provided already. Instead one has to build a reliable function that does so, respecting slashes and optional parameters